# Box Api Enterprise

Tags: box-api, box

I am asked by my company to do a Proof-Of-Concept for our document management using Box. We have an enterprise account. 
What I did is I added an app in my account  - to get my api keys ("client_id" and "client_secret").
Then after this Using the Box Api for .net4.0, I manage to connect my MVC app with our box account using OAuth2. 
I can now view files and folders as well as uploading files.

Now my problem is I need to restrict the files that can be viewed by the user logged.
I noticed that when changing the email that is use to log-in (we're using SSO)
The user info doesn't change.
I am using GetCurrentUserInformationAsync() method of the BoxApi V2.

Is it possible to perform user management using API?

(P.S. I am not the admin of our enterprise account)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change the email, you will be require the admin rights. First you need to create the email alias for that account and then you can replace the primary email address with your alias.